# Enabling Debug|Trace worker logs for google cloud dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Not able to enable the debug|trace level logging of the dataflow workers.

The documentation :https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging#SettingLevels

indicates the usage of `DataflowWorkerLoggingOptions` to programmatically overrides the default log level on the worker and enable the debug|trace level logging; however the interface is deprecated and no more present in bean-sdk 2.27.0 .

Has anyone been able to enable the worker level debugging in cloud dataflow; in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is still up to date and the interface is still present and will work.

The interface is deprecated because the Java-based Dataflow worker is not used when running a pipeline using Beam's portability framework. Quoting the deprecation message:

> `@deprecated` This interface will no longer be the source of truth for worker logging configuration once jobs are executed using a dedicated SDK harness instead of user code being co-located alongside Dataflow worker code. Please set the option below and also the corresponding option within `org.apache.beam.sdk.options.SdkHarnessOptions` to ensure forward compatibility.

So what you should do is follow the instructions that you linked and also set up logging in `SdkHarnessOptions`.

Comment: Right, I couldn't see the class because the scope of the jar beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java was set to runtime. Sorted thanks.